# Status field on ContractLineItem not available for reporting

Tags: picklist, formula-field, custom-report-type

I am creating a custom report Type with Service contract as primary object, and ContractLineItem as secondary object (both standard objects). On ContractLineItem, i need to include "Status" field (standard field) on the layout, but i can't see it anywhere among the list of fields available for ContractLineItem

Any ideas why its not there? Any workarounds? I am thinking of creating a custom formulae field, which will simply be equal to status field, and use this custom field to put on the report layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what type of field Status is, documentation says its a Picklist which operates on a formula

> The status of the contract line item. Status is determined by your
> organization’s current system date and the contract line item’s Start
> Date and End Date. The status is:
>
> Active - if the system date is greater than or equal to the Start Date and less than or equal to the End Date.
>
> Expired - if the system date is greater than the End Date.
>
> Inactive - if the system date is less than the Start Date.

You wont see this field while creating your custom formula field as well, so alternatively you can create a custom formula field and implement the above mentioned logic to it.